# How can I bold one item of a CharSequence used in an AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Just a quick question.  I have an alert dialog popup that gives the user a short list of options.

I would like one of these items displayed bold.  This is the basic code I'm using for the option list. I want "option1" to be bold, and all other options regular.  Is there any way to achieve this without using custom textviews or something?

```
CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[] {"option1", "option2", "option3"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick an option");
builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // my actions
    }
});
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 7):

You could do with `SpannableString`:

```
String b = "boldOption";
SpannableString boldOption = new SpannableString(b);
boldOption.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), 0, b.length(),0);
CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[] {boldOption, "option2", "option3"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick an option");
builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // my actions
}
});
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) in your option1: `Html.fromHtml("<b>option1</b>")`

```
CharSequence options[] = new CharSequence[] {Html.fromHtml("<b>option1</b>"), "option2", "option3"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick an option");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // my actions
            }
        });
        builder.show();
```

Comment: This is perfect because I can also make bold (<b>) part of a string. Thanks!